# C# shutdown function on Cosmos?

Tags: c#, operating-system, cosmos

I've been doing simple OSdev with C# in cosmos, but I've found out that contradictory to the tutorials I've been following, there's no sys library so i'm unable to run shutdown and reboot functions. Does anyone know any alternate ways of solving my problem? Code snippets are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The function is:

```
Cosmos.System.Power.Shutdown();
```

or

```
Cosmos.System.Power.Reboot();
```

to reboot